# Pass parametar througth function and show it

Tags: angularjs

I have problem with passing params with one function to another.

I am passing params like this:

```
        <div ng-click="changeView('distance')">EXPAND
        </div>
```

And in my controller

```
$scope.changeView = function (params) {
        $scope.currentView = params;
    };
```

I have more pages with more option. In my option I am selecting team, but I want to show depending on my changeView.

This is my select for teams

```
<select style="width: 100%;" ng-model="selectedTeam" ng-options="x.team_name for x in teams" ng-change="changeLocation(selectedTeam.team_id);" 
</select>
```

And this is in my controller for changeLocation

```
 $scope.changeLocation = function (teamId) {
        $scope.showPlayer = true;
        if ($scope.currentView == undefined) {
            $state.go('activity-statistic.activity-statistic-team-heart', { teamId: teamId }, { reload: false });
        }
        else {
            $state.go('activity-statistic.activity-statistic-team-' + $scope.currentView + '', { teamId: teamId }, { reload: false });
        }

    };
```

When I want to change location, my $scope.curentView is undefined always.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its looks like that your `$scope.changeView` and `$scope.changeLocation` both belong to different controllers $scope has its scope only in the current controller that why its showing undef

You can use `$rootscope` instead for global scope something like

```
$scope.changeView = function (params) {
        $rootscope.currentView = params;
    };
```

then change

```
 if ($scope.currentView == undefined)
```

to

```
if ($rootscope.currentView == undefined)
```